# Recovering SHIFT-DELETEd files?

Tags: data-recovery, delete, undelete

I just shift-deleted some important pdf-files from my dual-boot system. The files were originally on Windows drive, but I deleted them from Ubuntu. 
I just used Foremost to recover, but it returns more than 1000 files, with numbered-names. I can neither open the file, nor find my desired!

Is there any way that I can recover my files using, say, their names, or the directory which have been deleted from?

Thanks

Comment: In Windows, you could try recuva(http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download), the free version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other `Undelete` utilities? If nothing else `testdisk` has undelete feature as well.

Comment: I used extundelete with following code: sudo extundelete --restore-all --after 1357027200 --output-dir '/home/username/Desktop/' /dev/sda1 It gives the error of :  failed to read-only open device "/dev/sda1": Error code 2133571347

Comment: @Sadjad extundelete would only work on ext* partitions i expect.